# transform helm values.schema.json (jsonschema) to values.yaml

Tags: kubernetes-helm, jsonschema

I have a helm v3 related question for you. Do you know if there is some lib out there that can generate a `values.yaml` file from a `values.schema.json` file? So it generates comments from `description` fields above each property when it has such a field?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: We have an extensive schema and see that as our source of truth for mostly anything. We want to automate generating a values.yaml file from the schema. But now I am repeating myself. What is not clear on your end?

Comment: I know nothing about helm, and everything about JSON Schema. A breif google shows me a bit about helm values.yaml file. I can't see how it would relate to a JSON Schema. What am I missing here? My apologies 